# What's the best way to iterate over items in javascript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, undefined

I recently came accross a different way of looping though an array in Javascript.

I used to write loops something like this:

```
for (var len = 0; len < testData.length; len++) {
  total = total + testData[len];
}
```

I read some code that did it this way:

```
for (var len = 0; testData[len]; len++) {
  total = total + testData[len];
}
```

I was wondering how these would perform so I used [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/for-until-length-vs-until-undefined/10) to find it out. The results are pretty amazing. I expected the second method to be a bit it faster than the first, but it's actually much, much faster.

Is there a down side I'm missing here? Or is this the best way to loop through the items of a list.

**Update:**

*gray state is coming* and [*Diode*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12357692/31722) pointed me to a simple flaw in the testcase which made is seem to be faster.

After correcting the mistake, this is the fastest:

```
var datalen = testData.length;
for (var len = 0; len <datalen; len++) {
     total = total + testData[len];
}
```

**Update 2:**

After testing in some more browsers this testcase takes a different direction again. 
Only in Chrome and Opera the normal for loop is the fastest. In other all other browsers *Shmiddty*'s way is just a bit faster.

```
var i = testData.length, sum=0;
while (i--){
    sum += testData[i];
}
```

Comment: If you want to add a value to a variable, you should use `+=` instead of repeating the variable.

Comment: When you say "best", what are you looking for? Speed, code readability, reliability? What kind of array are you looping?

Comment: If there are falsy values in `testData` then the second loop will stop prematurely. That could be part of the "performance increase" you're seeing.

Comment: It's just some sample code. I came across this when optimizing for speed, for a game. Iterating over a collection of complex objects, enemies in this case.

Comment: Btw. I added the link to the jsPerf.

Comment: @Sorskoot: If you can be certain that all the items will be objects, then this is a good, safe approach

Comment: But your JSPerf test is very flawed. It appears to be so fast because it is stopping at the first iteration because of the `0` value. Change the initialization to start with `1` instead of `0`, then compare. `for (var i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {`

Comment: Corrected JSPerf test shows a very different result. http://jsperf.com/for-until-length-vs-until-undefined/7

Comment: I'd be interested to see the performance result of the method that I posted.

Comment: @Sorskoot - It was me who found it ;(    .... :D

Comment: I think the comment by gray state was 2 minutes earlier, I'll add a link to your comment. Thank you very much for helping out.

Comment: " sad ;( You didn't see my answer " ... ha..ha.. just joking ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also do a loop like so:

```
var i = testData.length;

while (i--){
    console.log(testData[i]);
}
```

Note that it traverses the array *backwards*.

Or, for a summation:

```
var i = testData.length, sum=0;

while (i--){
    sum += testData[i];
}
```

Comment: I added it to the testcase. Surprisingly the regular for-loop is faster.

Comment: It seems to be very close. http://jsperf.com/for-until-length-vs-until-undefined/9

Comment: I've tried some other browsers and in some browsers this way is actually the fastest...

Comment: These test cases run with Arrays of length 1000. If the lists are significantly shorter the test results change. I can not explain any of these performance results.

Comment: Likely due to varying optimizations in each javascript engine.

Answer (score 13):

I'd argue that the first form is better. The second form has some issues. What if you have a sparse array that contains `falsy` values? Like: `var testData = [ "text", undefined, false, 0, 5 ];`

I also expect the first form to perform better. Especially if you 'cache' the value of `testData.length` Like so:

```
var i, len = testData.length;
for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
  total = total + testData[i];
}
```

Comment: Good idea about caching the variable, but I still think a simple null/falsish check, as testData[len] is faster. +1 for commenting about the falsy values.

Comment: To avoid above problems, you can use condition (testData[len] != void 0). this will be true for all defined values.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh The problem with that is `undefined === void 0` is still true.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh: You can have a defined property with the `undefined` value. But aside from that, if you're going to do such a comparison, then you might as well compare the index to the length.

Comment: yes so after last element, next elem will be undefined, i guess that is what we are checking.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh I have updated the post with example test-data that breaks `== void 0` (aka `== undefined`). I did this by adding `undefined` as a value to the array being iterated.

Comment: In the jsPerf test case I compared both the cached and uncached version of the length. Caching the length does benefit the speed.

Comment: I'm guessing that, since this is probably the most widely used form of a loop, it is highly optimized in each respective javascript engine.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**: I was wrong, `forEach` is very slow! It seems loops are better

---

You should use `forEach`, which is defined in ECMAScript 5th edition.

```
testData.forEach(function(val,i,arr){
    total += val;
});
```

The arguments are:

- `val` is the current value
- `i` is the current index
- `arr` is the array

you don't have to use all of them:

```
testData.forEach(function(val){
    total += val;
});
```

And for the browsers that don't support it, this shim can be used:

```
if(!Array.prototype.forEach){
    Array.prototype.forEach = function(fn, scope) {
        for(var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; ++i) {
            fn.call(scope || this, this[i], i, this);
        }
    }
}
```

See [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for more information.

Comment: I totally forgot about forEach. I added it to the jsPerf. Alhough it's an obvious solution, it turns out to be the slowest way to iterate.

Comment: @Sorskoot Weird... I thought that it should be faster because it's native code. Maybe it's because it needs a function, so the scope chain grows. Curiosly I am starting a project using `forEach`, I will change it to a loop, thanks for your jsperf comparison

Comment: @Oriol: It has nothing to do with the scope chain; scope is static in JavaScript.  The problem with `forEach` is that function invocation is not free -- in fact, as you can see, it is quite expensive.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Shmiddt's answer, you could use a loop backwards. it seems it's a little faster than a while backwards on Firefox, and on Chrome they tie:

```
var total = 0;
for (var len = testData.length-1; len >=0; len--) {
  total += testData[len];
}
```

Test: http://jsperf.com/for-until-length-vs-until-undefined/10

Answer (score 1):

With regards to performance, `testData[len]` simply checks if the element is defined and not null/false/"falsish", which is faster than a comparison, and especially retrieving testData.length for each iteration.

So the second way is faster, but not more reliable - as correctly stated by Frits van Campen.

Answer (score 1):

Your setup code inserts 0 which causes the loop to break on first condition

```
var testData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  testData.push(i);  // pushes 0 to `testData`
}


for (var len = 0; testData[len]; len++) {   // loop breaks on first condition-check as testData[0] is 0.
  total = total + testData[len];
}
```

Change the setup code as given below and see the difference

```
var testData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  testData.push(i+1);
}
```

http://jsperf.com/for-until-length-vs-until-undefined/6